# Find and replace running in a never ending loop

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am currently using this code snippet in my script for replacing text in an ASCII file

```
        Dim fso, inputFile, outputFile
        Dim str As String
        Const quote As String = """"
        Dim MyFile As String = Folder & "\client-1\com\company\assembleegameclient\parameters\Parameters.class.asasm"

        fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        inputFile = fso.OpenTextFile(MyFile, 1)
        str = inputFile.ReadAll
        str = Replace(str, quote & TextBox1.Text & quote, quote & TextBox3.Text & quote)
        outputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(MyFile, True)
        outputFile.Write(str)


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
```

I put the threading at the end of the to see if it would fix the problem by waiting, but it doesn't work. The next step in the script requires this portion to be completely finished before proceeding.  Is there a way to attach this to a process with waitforexit? or something similar that works on strings?

It would be optimal if it would output the number of changes that were made and that it was complete.

Comment: you should add some error handling - are you sure the call to CreateTextFile succeeds? To me it seems like that file is still open sine you opened it using OpenTextFile but I see no Close call..

Comment: after I get errors and stop the application I have a command to delete the temporary directory "Folder", but it says one of the files in still in use.  If I stop the run and look in the folder everything has been deleted except for "MyFile". The strings in the file are replaced properly which is the odd thing.  I will try and add a close call

Comment: I added in `inputFile.Close()` after the replace command, but it still thinks the file is in use

Comment: Your question says "never ending loop", but you have no loop. You say "to see if it would fix the problem", but you don't describe any problem, and you say "it doesn't work" but don't explain what that means. Your comment says "after I get errors", but you don't describe the errors at all. What exactly would you like us to help you with?

Comment: I apologize for not making this clear. A little bit about my process:  I have a .swf the I decompile into a temp directory. Then one of the decopile files is modified with the replace command. then the swf is recompiled and the temp directory is deleted.  The error I get comes from the deletion process.  The file used in the relace command still thinks it is in use so it cannot be deleted. Also the recompile process begins before the replace command is finished as well. I would like to make the replace run for a finite amount of time and then finish before being recompiled and deleted.